# Concatenated many strings in PHP easily

Tags: php

The following code is correct:

```
$str = "INSERT INTO table ('".$val1."',"."'".$val2."'".","."'".$val3."'".","."'".$val4."')";
```

but the code below is incorrect:

```
$str = "INSERT INTO table ('".$val1."',"."'".$val2."'".","."".$val3."'".","."'".$val4."')";
```

The above example is small but you can see that larger cases of the above are annoying to debug when one misses out a ' or a ".  Is there a better way of concatenating strings in PHP?  I want to have variables having single inverted commas on bother sides and I want the string to be made using double inverted commas.

There must be a better way.. I write a lot of queries from PHP that talk to an Oracle DB and I am constantly making mistakes with these strings!!

Thank you :).

Comment: Step 1: Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), prepared statements, and placeholders. Step 2: .... Step 3: Profit.

Comment: @mu is too short: pdo oracle driver is not recommended for production, unfortunately

Comment: @mu is too short: he meant that `...` should be `???`

Comment: @zerkms: Right, too late to edit. Shame about the Oracle driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$str = sprintf("INSERT INTO table ('%s', '%s', ...", $val1, $val2);
```

or use prepared statements

Comment: Excellent.. that will save me a huge amount of time!

Comment: Looks very clean, but I think you should wrap $val1 and $val2 with mysql_real_escape_string() as other noticed here.

Comment: @Sergiy: it is oracle, not mysql. And I **did notice** that prepareds are preferred

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
$str = "INSERT INTO table ('$val1','$val2','$val3')";
```

Comment: Awesome.. I didn't know you could do that (duh :P).  Best solution so far +1.

Answer (score 2):

Use prepared statements for that: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

*Never* just concatenate arbitrary values to create a SQL statement. You will create millions of SQL injection holes in you application. http://xkcd.com/327/

At the very least, use mysql_real_escape_string or equivalent.

I recommend you do some reading about [security](http://phpsec.org/library/) and application design before writing any PHP application of consequence.

Comment: Really valuable advice +1.  See comments above about PDO Oracle driver though.  Loving the XKCD .

Comment: With mysql_real_escape_string(), even though I am using an Oracle DB, I think it would ensure my queries are safe even though it's intended for MySQL right?  Can't seem to find any Oracle equivalent.

Comment: @alemaster: for oracle the better approach is to use prepared statements with `oci_parse()`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
echo implode(",", array(
   '"'.$val1.'"',
   '"'.$val2.'"',
   '"'.$val3.'"',
));
```

But I must say that you can do it much easier with prepared statements.

Comment: I like it but I think I would make the same number of mistakes with this :P.

Answer (score 0):

create your own function with http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php and foreach, and use sql escapeing for each params. see the example1 on page

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with large param sets I prefer to put them into an **array** and join with `implode()` [function.implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) like in code below:

```
$params = array('param1','param2','param3');
$param_string = "('".implode("','", $params)."')";
```